# prove the identity tanA +cot A =2cosec2A

Tags: trigonometry

This question i tried doing tanA + cosA/sinA but then I cant continue the I tried the other side which I got 1/ 4sinAcosA and this doesn't look right I am stuck and I don't have a teacher to help m so if someone could help me that would mean so much.

Comment: Why not also write $\tan$ as $\sin/\cos$ and simplify? RHS has a wrong numerical factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\tan(A)+\cot(A)&=\frac{\sin(A)}{\cos(A)}+\frac{\cos(A)}{\sin(A)}\\&=\frac{\sin^2(A)+\cos^2(A)}{\sin(A)\cos(A)}\\&=\frac2{2\sin(A)\cos(A)}\\&=\frac2{\sin(2A)}\\&=2\operatorname{cosec}(2A).\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much but how did you get that 2/2sin()cos() this is where I get confused

Comment: @maryjames Use $\sin^2A+\cos^2A=1$ in the third $=$, then $\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A$ in the fourth.

Comment: thank you very much i appricate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\tan A+\cot A=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}+\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}=\frac{\sin^2A+\cos^2A}{\sin A\cos A}$$

You can then use the Pythagorean identity in addition to multiplying the top and bottom by $2$.

Comment: Nice but looks more like an answer than a hint.

Comment: Thank you very much